# Tomcat 9: "FindClass Main failed" error when starting the service

Tags: startup, tomcat9

I have this error when I'm starting the service.

std-err.log:

```
2018-09-25 02:03:59 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
Exception in thread "main" The data area passed to a system call is too small.

Failed to start service
2018-09-25 02:04:57 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
Exception in thread "main" The data area passed to a system call is too small.

Failed to start service
```

Commons-deamon.log:

```
[2018-09-25 02:03:45] [info]  [ 3148] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 32-bit) started
[2018-09-25 02:03:46] [info]  [ 3148] Service Tomcat9 name Apache Tomcat 9.0 Tomcat9
[2018-09-25 02:03:49] [info]  [ 3148] Service 'Tomcat9' installed
[2018-09-25 02:03:49] [info]  [ 3148] Commons Daemon procrun finished
[2018-09-25 02:03:58] [info]  [ 5196] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 32-bit) started
[2018-09-25 02:03:58] [info]  [ 5196] Starting service 'Tomcat9' ...
[2018-09-25 02:03:59] [info]  [ 4128] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 32-bit) started
[2018-09-25 02:03:59] [info]  [ 4128] Running 'Tomcat9' Service...
[2018-09-25 02:03:59] [info]  [ 5124] Starting service...
[2018-09-25 02:04:04] [error] [ 3324] FindClass Main failed
[2018-09-25 02:04:04] [error] [ 5124] Failed to start Java
[2018-09-25 02:04:04] [error] [ 5124] ServiceStart returned 4
[2018-09-25 02:04:05] [info]  [ 4128] Run service finished.
[2018-09-25 02:04:05] [info]  [ 4128] Commons Daemon procrun finished
[2018-09-25 02:04:04] [error] [ 5196] Failed to start 'Tomcat9' service
[2018-09-25 02:04:05] [error] [ 5196] The data area passed to a system call is too small.
[2018-09-25 02:04:05] [info]  [ 5196] Start service finished.
[2018-09-25 02:04:05] [error] [ 5196] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 5 (Failed to start service)
[2018-09-25 02:04:05] [error] [ 5196] The data area passed to a system call is too small.
[2018-09-25 02:04:56] [info]  [ 8068] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 32-bit) started
[2018-09-25 02:04:56] [info]  [ 8068] Starting service 'Tomcat9' ...
[2018-09-25 02:04:57] [info]  [ 6960] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 32-bit) started
[2018-09-25 02:04:57] [info]  [ 6960] Running 'Tomcat9' Service...
[2018-09-25 02:04:57] [info]  [ 3648] Starting service...
[2018-09-25 02:04:58] [error] [ 5828] FindClass Main failed
[2018-09-25 02:04:58] [error] [ 3648] Failed to start Java
[2018-09-25 02:04:59] [error] [ 3648] ServiceStart returned 4
[2018-09-25 02:04:59] [info]  [ 6960] Run service finished.
[2018-09-25 02:05:00] [info]  [ 6960] Commons Daemon procrun finished
[2018-09-25 02:05:00] [error] [ 8068] Failed to start 'Tomcat9' service
[2018-09-25 02:05:00] [error] [ 8068] The data area passed to a system call is too small.
[2018-09-25 02:05:00] [info]  [ 8068] Start service finished.
[2018-09-25 02:05:01] [error] [ 8068] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 5 (Failed to start service)
[2018-09-25 02:05:01] [error] [ 8068] The data area passed to a system call is too small.
```

It is very strange, I don't understand what Main class is it looking for. I was looking on web for this error but I found only similar ones, but not the exact one.

Can anybody help?
Thanks.